# copy kvm image from ceph to other storage

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, proxmox, ceph

A while ago I created a ceph storage cluster and connected it to proxmox2 according to the method described in http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Storage:_Ceph.
We have some kvm images running on the ceph storage that where originaly just for testing purpose but over time they are becoming more and more important for our company. Because I don't consider the ceph storage as production ready yet, I would like to move the kvm images to our ISCSI storage. Does anyone know how I can copy the images from ceph to other storage? Knowing how to copy them to local storage would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily transfer images in and out of Ceph RADOS with the `rbd` command. I am currently using libvirt to manage my KVM images, so my paths may be different.

The libvirt configuration for one of my virtual machines uses an RBD disk image located at `data/vm-www`. To see that RBD pool, I can use the `rbd ls -p data` command. For any other command, such as getting information about the image, you can use a shortened form: `rbd info data/vm-www`, instead of the longer `rbd info -p data vm-www`.

Now that you have verified you can find the image, use this command to save it to a local file: `rbd export data/vm-www www.raw`. `www.raw` is now a file that contains your virtual machine's disk, and you can tell your libvirt or qemu-kvm command to use it directly as a raw file. Alternatively, you can use qemu-img to convert it to a different format, such as qcow2.

I do not have experience with RBD snapshots, but the `rbd export` command lists a "--snap" option, presumably to be used with information that you can get from `rbd snap ls data/vm-www`.

Hope this helps!